# error: no such module 'Runes' in iOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, argo

I am actually using runes in ios hybrid project with both objective c and swift code. i have added runes as dependency using github submodule and linked binaries. Now app is throwing below error:

```
Argo/Sources/Argo/Types/Decoded/Applicative.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'Runes'

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal armv7
    CompileSwiftSources normal armv7 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwift normal arm64
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(4 failures)
```

i took latest code update of both argo and runes.

Comment: Have you tried importing Runes into Project Settings -> Build Phases under Link binary with libraries?

Comment: @LawrenceTan yes i did.